# Scrapy CrawlerProcess not find correct data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the different 18 boats on this [url](https://www.clickandboat.com/uk/boat-hire/search?where=Spain) (only the first page for a start).

But to do so, I only want the boat details url which can be found in the div.col-6-12.mobile-col-1-1.envItem > article > data-product-url

In order to do so I did the following script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    
    def parse(self, response):
        for boat in response.css('div.col-6-12.mobile-col-1-1.envItem'):
            yield {
                'url': boat.css('article::attr("data-product-url")').get()
            }
            
# run spider
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(QuotesSpider, start_urls = ['https://www.clickandboat.com/uk/boat-hire/search?where=Spain'])
process.start()
```

The script is working and I receive 18 urls of boats details but they belong to boats which are not in the first page of the url that I wanted to scrape.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the list of the urls of the boats details (which can be found in div.col-6-12.mobile-col-1-1.envItem > article > data-product-url) of the url I put above ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this css selector to get the data:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'

    def parse(self, response):
        for boat in response.css('div#product-list.productList'):
            yield {
                'url': boat.css('div.col-6-12.mobile-col-1-1.envItem>article.boatAd.js-boatAd::attr("data-product-url")').getall()
            }

# run spider
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(QuotesSpider, start_urls = ['https://www.clickandboat.com/uk/boat-hire/search?where=Spain'])
process.start()
```